# Building proxies hub

Tags: java, architecture, proxy

First of all I'm gathering information about this question and so that i could implement this feature in a more elegant way.

Let's look at the picture below
[image]

*The target server (green circle)*

This is an api server that I use to fetch some data.

Features:

- Only `https` connection
- Response in json format.
- Can accept `get` requests like these [ https://api.server.com/user=1&option&api_key=? ]

*Proxy controller (blue square)*

It's a simple server that stores list of proxies; Send and receive some data; And I want to talk about the software that i will to run on top of it.

Features:

- Proxy list
- Api keys list

I think it should be a `hashmap` that stores ip=>token list or database table if I want to scale my application.

*Workers*

Just analyze a json response and pass data to the db.

Let's go closer to the proxy controller server.

The first idea:

- Create `newFixedThreadPoolExecutor`
- Pass url/token to worker: server.submit(new Worker(url, token, proxy))
- Worker analyze the data and pass it to db.

But in my opinion this solution is quite big and hard to maintain, I want to engage endpoint that gather stats, kill or spawn new workers and so on.

The second idea:

1. Worker generates an request like https://host/user=1&option=1
2. Pass it to the Proxy controller
3. Proxy controller assign to the request the api key and proxy server
4. Execute the request
5. Accept the response
6. Pass it back to a worker (I think that the best idea is to put a load balancer between workers and proxy controller).

This solution seems to me quite hacky. For example if the worker is dead the proxy server sends bunch of requests to the dead worker and it could led to dataloss.

The third idea:

The same as the second but instead of sending data directly to the worker the proxy controller pass it to some bus. I find some information about apache camel that allow me to organize this solution. In this case the dead worker is dead worker and dataloss equals zero (maybe).

Of course all three cases don't handle an errors. Some errors can be solved by resending the request with additional data. Some errors can be solved by re-span the workers.

So in your opinion what is the best solution in this case? Do I miss some hidden problems that can appear later? Which tools I should use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are trying to reach?
Maybe you consider using this architecture: 
NGINX (proxy + load balance) -> WORKER SERVERS -> DB SERVER (maybe use some NoSQL like Cassandra)

Comment: This case was okay if ngnix could support multiple proxies and sign the request with tokens associated with host/port of the proxy.